# PHP CURL SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled error

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, openssl, php-curl, ubuntu-22.04

I am using amazon aws with ubuntu 22.04. In my system I have installed OPENSSL version 3 and installed self signed certificate. When I am trying to make a cURL call, it works for some call and shows error `SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled` for some cURL calls.
Can anyone help me out how to solve "SSL routines::unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled" error from cURL?

I tried adding custom openssl config file, but it still shows the same error.